# How can i filter data on change of checkbox using angular 2?

Tags: angular

I want to perform filter on my data using checkbox. I have two check box 1 - Fun, 2 - Learning on click of check box data should filter.

component.html

```
<div class="type">
     <label>ACTIVITY TYPE</label>
     <div class="form-group">                                
          <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                       <input type="checkbox" (change)="typefilter($event)" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" #type> Learning
                    </label>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="checkbox">
                     <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" (change)="typefilter($event)" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" #type> Fun
                      </label>
                 </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
type: boolean = false;
typefilter(event){
  if(event.target.checked){
    this.activityService.getActivities().then(activities => this.activities = activities.filter(a => a.type == this.type));      
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `typefilter` method ever triggered when you check the checkbox and if it is, what is the state of `event.target` and `event.target.checked` then?

Comment: When i click on check box both option getting checked @ex0dm3nt

Comment: Ok, but does your `typefilter` method gets triggered? Could you add `console.log(event);` or `console.log(event.target);` at the beginning of your `typefilter` method, and then check your browser console if anything is logged there when you check the checkbox?

Comment: after `console.log(event.target);` i am getting `<input name="type" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="type" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" ng-reflect-model="true">` @ex0dm3t

Comment: What does a single object from `this.activites` look like?

Comment: activities: HomeActivity[];

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, i was more interested in what the `HomeActivity` object and it's properties look like.

Comment: `export class HomeActivity {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  slug: any;
  type:any;
  sport: string;
  vendor: string;
  sportslug: any;
  vendorslug: any;
  location: string;
  days: number;
  price: number;
  image: string[];
  max_people?:number;
  min_people?:number;
}` @ex0dm3nt

Comment: @RomilLodaya The reason why both are checked is because of the ngModel pointing to the same, meaning `type`. But I don't understand how this would filter anything separate. Since you are just checking if either is checked, the filter will be the same for both since you are just filtering based on true??

Comment: How can i filter according to type?

Comment: `type` property in your `HomeActivity` is of type `any`, but your `type` property from your component is of type `boolean`. When you receive data from your service, if no item from `activities` array has `type` property set as `boolean`, your filter will not work.

Comment: I should have lead with this question: what do you want your filter to do? :)

Comment: But i am passing this.type in filter

Comment: Yes, like comment from ex0dm3nt, what are the types you want to filter, because now it's filtering you activities by `true`, since `this.type` will be true when it's checked and you are filtering like so: `.filter(a => a.type == this.type)` which filters `a.type` being true :)

Comment: `export class HomeActivity { id: number; name: string; slug: any; type:any; sport: string; vendor: string; sportslug: any; vendorslug: any; location: string; days: number; price: number; image: string[]; max_people?:number; min_people?:number; }`

Comment: if i click on Fun. The activity having type FUN should get display or if i click on learning The activity having type Learning should get or if i click on both both activity data should display display@ex0dm3nt

Comment: Ok, thanks, now it's clear :).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments above, you can try this:

```
<div class="type filters__item">
     <label>ACTIVITY TYPE</label>
     <div class="form-group">                                
          <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                       <input type="checkbox" (change)="typefilter($event, 'Learning')" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" #type> Learning
                    </label>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="checkbox">
                     <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" (change)="typefilter($event, 'Fun')" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" #type> Fun
                      </label>
                 </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And your component code:

```
type: String = '';
typefilter(event, typeOfActivity){
  if(event.target.checked){
    this.type = typeOfActivity;
    this.activityService.getActivities().then(activities => this.activities = activities.filter(a => a.type == this.type));      
  }
}
```

You don't even need `this.type` anymore as you can use `typeOfActivity` in your filter, but i have put it there for clarity purpose.

Comment: remove `this.type = typeOfActivity;` line from the `typefilter` method and `[(ngModel)]="type"` from checkboxes in your HTML template.

Comment: working man but if both 1st i click on fun then it shows fun filter data and then if i click on learning it should perform both filter data @ex0dm3nt

Answer (score 0):

Some changes to the answer provided by ex0dm3nt, since I think that it really doesn't work as intended. Having the same `ngModel` in both would check the both checkboxes when clicking on either. Also I think you do not want the possibility to click both checkboxes, so here I have disabled the other one in case one is clicked. Might be a bit clunky, but should work as you wish :)

```
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="fun" (change)="typefilter($event)" [(ngModel)]="learning"> Learning
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="learning" (change)="typefilter($event)" [(ngModel)]="fun"> Fun
```

and then in your TS file first check that one of the checkboxes are checked, after that is it either `fun` or `learning` that is true, so you know if you need to filter type by "fun" or "learning"

```
fun: boolean = false;
learning: boolean = false;
```

**EDIT:** Made some changes to code, since I think you shouldn't make unncessesary API calls, just retrieve the data once and than toggle those values from the original array:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData().then(data => {
    this.origActivities = data // original data to filter
    this.activities = data; // displays all activities upon initialization
  })
}

typefilter(event: any, filterValue: string) {
  this.activities = this.origActivities;
  if(event.target.checked) {
     if(this.fun && !this.learning){
        this.activities = this.origActivities.filter(a => a.type == filterValue); 
     }
     else if (this.learning && !this.fun) {
        this.activities = this.origActivities.filter(a => a.type == filterValue); 
     }
     else if (this.learning && this.fun) {
       this.activities = this.origActivities;
     }
  }
  else { // user unchecks value 
     if(this.fun) {
       this.activities = this.origActivities.filter(a => a.type == "fun"); 
     }
     else if (this.learning) {
       this.activities = this.origActivities.filter(a => a.type == "learning"); 
     }
   }
 }
```

For a limited time, here is a [**demo plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fr1i8Mx7TXgDc89iYmRN?p=preview)!

Comment: Your code is not working @AJT_82 data is not filtering

Comment: Updated my answer with a demo plunker, check it out :)

Comment: Yea man its working but this is working like radio button you can only check one at a time.

Comment: Sure, so how would you like it to work, you have not mentioned it :) Tell me, and I will adjust my answer accordingly :)

Comment: if i click on fun then it shows fun filter data and then if i click on learning it should perform both filter data and if i unchecked both show all data

Comment: Updated answer. This becomes quite comprehensive, since there are quite many possibilities, so all have to be different states needs to be checked and actions performed accordingly. But that works now as you wish.